# Velocity induced by a straight vortex filament

Tags: fluid-dynamics, aerodynamics, potential-flow

Consider a straight vortex filament as shown below. At each point, there's a point vortex of strength $\it T$. Consider that a point $P$ is there on the outermost circle of flow induced by the vortex about the origin $O$. That is the point $P$ lies in the plane containing the flow induced by the vortex at $O$. So, the only point on the vortex filament that will induce a flow at point $P$ is $O$.

Therefore, the vortex at point $O^{'}$ will not induce any flow at point $P$. Vortex at point $O^{'}$ can only induce flow at those points that are in the plane containing the flow induced by the vortex at $O^{'}$.

[image: Vortex Filament]

So, my question is how Biot-Savart Law is applied for a straight filament vortex? How can the segment $dl$ induce a flow at a point $P$ that is not in the plane? Only the vortex centered at the point of intersection of line and perpendicular from point $P$ to the line can induce the flow at $P$. Please clear my query.

[image: Biot-Savart Law]

Comment: Biot-Savart law explicitly states that a vortex filament of length $dl$ will induce velocity everywhere in the fluid, not just in the plane perpendicular to it. For a straight line vortex, here's a derivation: http://web.mit.edu/16.unified/www/SPRING/fluids/Spring2008/LectureNotes/f06.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the link! That cleared my doubt. I was not thinking in terms of 3D.